# Openshift 4.6 Node and Master Config Files

Tags: openshift

Where is the Openshift Master and Node Host Files in v4.6

Previously hosted below in v3

Master host files at /etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml
Node host files at /etc/origin/node/node-config.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your current kubelet configuration using the following procedures instead of the configuration file on the node hosts like OCPv3. Because the kubelet configuration was managed dynamically as of OCPv4.
Further information is here, [Generating a file that contains the current configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/#generating-a-file-that-contains-the-current-configuration).
You can check it using above reference procedures([Generate the configuration file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/#generate-the-configuration-file)) or oc CLI as follows.

```
$ oc get --raw /api/v1/nodes/${NODE_NAME}/proxy/configz | \
  jq '.kubeletconfig|.kind="KubeletConfiguration"|.apiVersion="kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1"'
```

Answer (score 0):

These files no longer exist in the same for as in OCP 3. To change anything on the machines themselves, you'll need to create MachineConfigs, as CoreOS is an immutable Operating System. If you change anything manually on the filesystem and reboot the machine, your changes will typically be reset.

- To modify Worker Nodes, often the setting you are looking for can be configured via a `kubeletConfig`: [Managing nodes - Modifying Nodes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/nodes/nodes/nodes-nodes-managing.html#nodes-nodes-managing-about_nodes-nodes-jobs). Note that only [certain settings](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubelet/blob/master/config/v1beta1/types.go) can be changed, others cannot be changed at all.
- For the Master Config, it depends on what you want to do, as you will potentially change the setting via a `machineConfigPool` or for example edit API Server setting via `oc edit apiserver cluster`. So it depends on what you actually want to change.